# Doing sector-level disk I/O in OS X with user privileges

Tags: macos

I'm writing an application that is going to essentially be a sector-level disk eraser for external storage devices. It looks like the only way to do this is to work with the /dev/rdisk* devices in the filesystem. The problem is that only root can write to /dev/rdisk* so the application would have to be started with elevated privileges or it wouldn't work.

The thing is that Disk Utility is able to work at that level (because it can create filesystems) without any privilege escalation. I'm wondering how that is accomplished because I haven't really seen anything on Apple's website about it. Are they using some kind of trusted system call from Disk Utility down to the kernel level to enable this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have root permission to access the disk sectors. Disk Utility basically relies on `storagekitd` helper daemon which is running as root to do the low-level stuff.